# Is there an inherent risk in publishing other users' ids?

Tags: meteor

I have a collection called `Vouchers`. A user can, if they know the unique number ID of a Voucher, "claim" that voucher, which will give it a `user_id` attribute, tying it to them.

I'm at a point where I need to check a user's ID query against the existing database, but I'm wondering if I can do so on the client instead of the server (the client would be much more convenient because I'm using utility functions to tie the query form to the database operation.... it's a long story). If I do so on the client, I'll have to publish the entire Vouchers collection with correct `user_id` fields, and although I won't be showing those ids through any templates, they would be available through the console.

Is there an inherent risk in publishing all of the IDs like this? Can they be used maliciously even if I don't leave any specific holes for them to be used in?

Answer (score 1):

First, in general it sounds like a bad idea to publish all `user_ids` to the client. What would happen if you have 1 million users? That would be a lot of data.

Second, in specific, we cannot know if there is inherent risk in publishing your `user_id`s, because we do not know what could be done with it in your system. If you use a typical design of `user_id`s chosen by the user themselves (for instance email), then you MUST design your system to be safe even if an attacker has guessed the `user_id`.

Comment: Well, I would only be publishing the `user_id`s that were already attached to a Voucher, so it would only be showing the ids of users who had already signed up for one, not the entire Users database.

Comment: There is no difference in the dimension of this. Even for 1000 vouchers it would be starting to be inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

Short Version: not so good idea.

I have a similar setup up: user can sign-up, if she knows the voucher code. You can only publish those vouchers where the `user_id` is identical to the logged in user. All other checks like "does the user input correspond to a valid voucher?" must be handled on the server.

Remember: client code is **not** trusted.